# arrayWithContentsOfFile with plist returning partial keys on a 5.1 iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsarray, plist

I have the following method that reads a plist file[see the screenshot attached] and returns it as a mutable array:

```
+(NSMutableArray *)getSharersPlistArray:(NSString*)plist
{
    NSString *AppDetailPlist = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:plist ofType:@"plist"];
    NSMutableArray* toReturn = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:AppDetailPlist]];
    NSLog(@"toReturn:%@", toReturn);
    return toReturn;
}
```

The incomplete result of this on a iPad 1 / iOS 5.1 :

```
(
        {
        2 =         {
            image = "Icon-72.png";
            name = Email;
            type = ShareCell;
        };
    },
        {
        0 =         {
            image = "Icon-72.png";
            name = Share;
            type = ShareCell;
        };
    }
)
```

On the correct/complete result on a 5.1 or 6.0 simulator:

```
(
        {
        0 =         {
            image = "Icon-72.png";
            name = Facebook;
            type = ShareCell;
        };
        1 =         {
            image = "Icon-72.png";
            name = Twitter;
            type = ShareCell;
        };
        2 =         {
            image = "Icon-72.png";
            name = Email;
            type = ShareCell;
        };
    },
        {
        0 =         {
            image = "Icon-72.png";
            name = Share;
            type = ShareCell;
        };
        1 =         {
            image = "Icon-72.png";
            name = Follow;
            type = ShareCell;
        };
    }
)
```

I did validate the plist, and it looks OK:

find . -name '*plist' -exec plutil {} \;

./Share.plist: OK

Any ideas why? I would appreciate any insight )

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

1. clean your Xcode project;
2. delete the app from your iPad 1 / iOS 5.1 device.

Re-build/run.

Hope this fixes it.

Comment: yes.. that was the first thing I tried, so I've done it a number of times. But this problem seems to be consistent. Thanks Sergio.

Comment: restarted the device and it seems to work now. Really strange.